# Why amp-img srcset not work on mobile

Tags: amp-html

I try to use the amp-img srcset to speed up my webpage as follow:

```
<amp-img src=img/LOGO1.jpg srcset="img/LOGO1.jpg 1080w, img/LOGO414.jpg 414w" alt=lock width="985" height="265" layout=responsive></amp-img>
```

the problem is it can work when I change the browser width on desktop, but I check with my phone, the browser always show the "LOGO1.jpg".

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check my code, you need to write proper tag

```
<amp-img src="img/LOGO1.jpg" srcset="img/LOGO1.jpg 1080w, img/LOGO414.jpg 414w" alt="lock" width="985" height="265" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
```

Comment: Thank Bachcha Singh!
but my phone show the "LOGO1.jpg" not "LOGO414.jpg"

Comment: Please check the width of mobile in pixel hope this help

Comment: http://www.onsumlock.com/test03.html
Please try to see my page on your phone.  
I think not the width of mobile problem,   because the green image is 320px, and I try to edit the code to srcset="img/LOGO1.jpg 1080w, img/LOGO414.jpg 800w"    the phone will show LOGO1.jpg

Comment: @JoeLam let me check above link I will update you soon

Comment: @JoeLam I have checked working fine, Please take two different images for test

Comment: You can see the logo414.jpg have "414" at image right side

Comment: Hello @JoeLam I have gone through the documentation and this link https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-img/source/ as well. It is working fine only if I resize the browser window not with a mobile. there might be future update for this